# How to multi-criteria plot with porpotion and stack table under axis?

Tags: r, plot, percentage

I'm new to R and I'm stuck with this data.
The data provides genders, sleep duration on weekend and on weekday ( 3 columns) and I want to make a plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iYV7.png)
I could draw it separately for weekend and weekday. I've tried to use the same x-axis and make another dataframe to calculate porpotion to fill on y-axis, but it doesn't seem to work.
And I donot know how to stack another table at the bottom like that.
I need some help, thanks you all!
And [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12HR9W8Xs6Diwjl8cSj6SusF0_HlO16sq/view?usp=sharing) is the data I've collected with rstwd presents sleep duration on weekday and rstwk presents sleep duration on weekend etc ...

Comment: Can please share the data in a reproducible format.

Comment: I have problems with csv file so I uploaded an edited xlsx file which can be copied directly to R